# Doubt about the MultiBit wallet

Tags: multibit

I'm using the MultiBit wallet and I can't get my satoshis from faucetbox. I read on MultiBit page that the most secure way to receive a payment is generating a brand new wallet address.
That's my question, I'm using an old MultiBit wallet address on faucetbox, that can be the reason for this issue? I mean, not receiving my satoshis from faucetbox?
Sorry about my bad english :D
Peace for all.

Comment: Is That an old MultiBit address, but generated with the MultiBit that you currently have installed? I don't know faucetbox, but have you checked if they have a mininum payout or something?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, most faucets (not all) have a minimum payout of 20000 satoshis. Check the minimum payout of the faucet you are using. Try updating to one of the latest versions of multibit from [here](https://multibit.org/). Generate a new address and try again, it should work. Maybe because of the forks in the network the old address may not be valid.

Comment: Could you please explain further why old addresses would not be valid any more?

Comment: Adresses have remained backward compatible throughout the entire Bitcoin history, so old addresses remain valid.